# Subset a Dataframe by column vector of a different Dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, subset

Supposing i got a dataframe like this:

```
dfA<-data.frame(A=c(letters[1:3]),B=c(letters[4:6]),C=c(letters[7:9]))

>dfA
  A B C
1 a d g
2 b e h
3 c f i
```

and another one like this:

```
dfB<-data.frame(replicate(12,sample(0:5,5,rep=T)))
colnames(dfB)<-sample(letters[1:9],12,rep=T)

> dfB
  a a d d g e i c i a g h
1 0 3 3 2 2 1 2 4 1 2 4 0
2 2 2 3 0 0 0 4 4 1 5 2 1
3 4 5 0 3 2 4 3 5 1 4 2 3
4 0 1 0 4 4 3 2 2 1 2 3 1
5 4 0 2 1 2 4 0 5 5 0 5 1
```

**How could I refer to all columns from dfB, which have names contained in column A of dfA?**

I am quite new to R and searched this forum a lot, but couldn't get the exact answer.
I tried something like this: `sub<-subset(dfB, !colnames(dfB) %in% dfA$A)` with unsatisfying results so far.

The output I'd wanna get would be:

```
> sub
  a a c a
1 0 3 4 2
2 2 2 4 5
3 4 5 5 4
4 0 1 2 2
5 4 0 5 0
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `dfB[colnames(dfB) %in% dfA$A]` or `subset(dfB, select=colnames(dfB) %in% dfA$A)`

Comment: Worked! I hoped it would be that easy. Thank You

Comment: Could also use `dfB[match(dfA$A, names(dfB), 0L)]`

Answer (score 1):

as akrun pointed out in the comments

```
subset(dfB, select=colnames(dfB) %in% dfA$A)
```

works perfectly.